# remove first 0 in a binary string

Tags: c++, string

Given a binary string, for ex
           10101011111001
I want to delete the first zero(its the second one in the above case) and if there is no 0 then remove any 1, so the output for above string will be
           1101011111001.

If I do it using

```
 for( int i = 0 ; i < siz-1 ; i++ ){
      if( s[i] =='0' && bit ==1) {
         bit = 0;
      }else {
         ans = ans + s[i];
      }
 }  
 if( bit == 1  ) {
     cout << ans <<endl;
 }else {
     ans = ans + s[siz-1];
     cout << ans <<endl;
  }
```

The above solution gave me TLE and solution using erase function worked properly, what is causing this behaviour?

Note: Size of string can be a max of 10^5

Comment: Now that *is* an odd requirement. :)

Comment: @interjay: Time Limit Exceeded. Probably a problem on some online judge.

Comment: Why don't you `break` the loop after you found `bit` and then copy the rest without checking the unnecessary bit?

Comment: What is the solution using erase function?

Answer (score 1):

```
pos = s.find('0');
if (pos == string::npos) {
  result = s.substr(1);
} else {
  result = s.substr(0, pos) + s.substr(pos+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code(not proper code and not c++, just pseudo code)

```
int count=0;
bool zerofound==false;
while(yourstring.contains('0'))
{
 if(yourstring.elementAt(count)=='0')
 {
   yourstring.replace('0','');
   zerofound==true;
   break;
 }
  count++;
}
if(!zerofound)
{
  yourstring.replaceAt(0,'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a loop will be slow:

```
ans = ans + s[i];
```

It will need to make a copy of the string each time. Instead, you should use:

```
ans.push_back(s[i]);
```

which will modify the string in-place. This will give you linear runtime instead of quadratic runtime as you have now, which will be a major improvement for long strings.

For best results, you can also put `ans.reserve(siz);` before the loop so that no reallocations need to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code look like you need to print the string at the end anyway.
If it is the case, then another solution would be to examine each character and print it if it's not the first zero.

That way you avoid all operations on the string before printing.

Addendum: Obviously, to account for the possibility of not printing the last '1' when the string has only ones, a one-char buffer would be needed to actually print the previous char.